# How to select changeset to build in custom build in visualstudio.com

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I configured a solution in visualstudio.com with continuous deployment in an azure website.

I would like to create a custom build that lets me rebuild and deploy an arbitrary changeset. I created the build, but when I go to Queue a new build the Dropdown **What do you want to build** is disabled and locked with Latest sources.

[image: visualstudio.com screenshot]

How can I enable this selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue using Visual Studio 2013 to queue a build from Visual Studio Team Services.

There is a Hotfix for VS 2013 listed on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722.aspx) that fixed it for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722.aspx

> If you are using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Team Foundation
>   Server 2013, you might have problems modifying build process
>   parameters when you queue a build. [Get the KB 2898341 hotfix](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=327817).

Comment: OP wants to use the visualstudio.com web interface

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Online and Git, you might be able to use the [Override Checkout parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677712/167018) instead, either in the Build Definition itself or when you manually queue a new build.

[image: Queue Build with Override Checkout parameter]

The Override Checkout parameter accepts commit hashes, tags and branch names.

Comment: But how do you do this using the `https://<companyNameHere>.visualstudio.com` interface?

Comment: My apologies - I misread the question. There is a build.preview which allows much more granular build definitions to be created, and it seems like you can select a branch and/or specify a commit (https://youtu.be/aLprCE3uRHs?t=278) from the new queue build window - but I haven't tested this out personally.