# Queue build for non-default branch with git and VS

Tags: git, tfs, build, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I'm using Visual Studio's integration with git. I modified the build definition's **Source Settings** to monitor all git branches (`refs/heads/*`). This works perfectly for automatically triggered builds.

When I manually queue a new build from within Visual Studio, the only option is to queue the default build (e.g. if I default to `refs/heads/develop`, I can't queue `refs/heads/mybranch`). The workaround is to change the default temporarily in the build definition. Is there another way? Somehow to pass a parameter perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Parameters tab there is a "Checkout Override" where you can override exactly which branch to use for the build. There is no nice UI/Picker for the field, but you should be able to set the branch/commit to build right there.

[image: Checkout Override]

There is a pretty [simple editor in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677712/736079) to select the available tags.

Comment: But I've tried this and you cannot choose a branch as requested, only a commit or a tag! I tried `refs/heads/mybranch` and `mybranch`.

Comment: Use `origin/{BranchName}` instead, that seems to work.